# POST method getting converted to GET on SpringSource tc Server

Tags: javascript, tomcat, tcserver

I am using a simple html/javascript to post data to a servlet running on SpringSource tc Server, on first click the request is received as a GET rather than a POST, but on subsequent clicks servlet does receive a POST request. 
why is the request getting converted to a GET before reaching the service method on the servlet. what can be done it resolve it.

```
I tried opening that html/javascript file in chrome/firefox/IE browsers to see if it makes any difference, but still the same issue.

function formSubmit(){
document.forms['myForm'].action="https://myURL";
document.forms['myForm'].method='post';
    document.forms['myForm'].target='_blank';
    document.forms['myForm'].submit();
}

this is the code that I use on the html page to post the form data to the servlet.
```

Comment: That sounds very unlikely; the request type is set at the **browser**, not the server.  Perhaps there's something amiss with your client-side code.

Comment: I tried opening that html/javascript file in chrome/firefox/IE browsers to see if it makes any difference, but still the same issue.

function formSubmit(){
 document.forms['myForm'].action="https://myURL";
 document.forms['myForm'].method='post';
 document.forms['myForm'].target='_blank';
 document.forms['myForm'].submit();
}

this is the code that I use on the html page.

Comment: It's hard to read in the comment; perhaps you could edit the original question.

Comment: Exact tc Server runtime version number? It should be an Apache Tomcat version number with a letter on the end.